# Kubernetes secrets as environment variable add space character

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, environment-variables, configmap

I'm currently facing a weird issue with K8S. Indeed I'm creating a container with an envFrom statement and the env variable is pulled from a secret:

```
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
    name: my-super-secret
```

I have created the secret with the base64 encoded value, and when I echo the variable in the container it has added a space at the end, which is quite an issue since it's a password ;-)

Here's my secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-super-secret
data:
  DB_PASSWORD: base64encodedvalue
```

Does anyone could provide me with some guidance here ?
I absolutely can't figure out what's happening here ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you encode the value?

Using this (on Mac)

```
echo -n "base64encodedvalue" | base64
YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVl
```

I can access my values just fine in my Containers, without a trailing space.

```
echo YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVl | base64 -d
base64encodedvalue
```

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/

Comment: Hi, first thank you for tour answer. I do the same but without the -n. But when I decode the secret there is no trailing space. It seems that it comes when the env variable is injected. However, I will give a try to your fix.

Comment: The -n should fix your issue. As from the echo man page:      "-n    Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be achieved by appending `\c' to the end of the string."