# Base64 encoding is adding a new line

Tags: kubernetes, base64

I'm trying to encode a database string using base64 on the command line in linux.

Once I do I add the value to a secret in kubernetes but my application is failing to connect to the database due to the db string not being accepted. There seems to be a newline getting added when I check the value in lens and this is not there in a similar cluster in the same secret

jdbc:postgresql://test.xxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test

```
deirdre$ echo jdbc:postgresql://test.xxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test | base64 | tr -d "\n"
amRiYzpwb3N0Z3Jlc3FsOi8vdGVzdC54eHh4eHh4eC5ldS13ZXN0LTIucmRzLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vdGVzdAo=
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? or is there an issue with the /?

Answer (score 18):

You can fix those easy with

```
echo -n "string" | base64
```

"echo -n" removes the trailing newline character.

You can also see my last answer i gave to following Question
[Kubernetes secrets as environment variable add space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032810/kubernetes-secrets-as-environment-variable-add-space-character/68033302#68033302)

Answer (score 9):

the problem is that base64 adds the newline in order to be compatible with older systems that have a maximum line width. you can add the -w 0 option to the base64 command to change the behavior so that it no longer adds new lines.

in your example this would be

```
echo "jdbc:postgresql://test.xxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test" | base64 -w 0
```

which results in

```
amRiYzpwb3N0Z3Jlc3FsOi8vdGVzdC54eHh4eHh4eC5ldS13ZXN0LTIucmRzLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vdGVzdAo=
```

edit:

```
printf "%s" jdbc:postgresql://test.xxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test | base64 -w 0
```

produces the correct output which adds an additional newline in the base64 encoded string which is apparently required for the url to be recognized as properly ended

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I tried that actually but it produces the same encoded value, see how your output is the same as mine above? its really odd

Comment: hi. i am sorry, i seem to have missread the question. because base64 also adds additional '\n' characters every 76 characters. 

can you try using the output of: 
"printf "%s" jdbc:postgresql://test.xxxxxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test | base64 -w 0" 

if that doesn't work I am currently out of other ideas

Answer (score 3):

So please use `echo -n` to remove the line break before redirecting to `base64`; and use `base64 -w 0` to prevent `base64` itself to add line break into the output.

```bash
me@host:~ 
$ echo -n mypassword | base64 -w 0
bXlwYXNzd29yZA==me@host:~ # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< notice that no line break added after "==" due to '-w 0'; so me@host is on the same line
$ echo -n 'mypassword' | base64 -w 0
bXlwYXNzd29yZA==me@host:~ # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< notice adding single quotes does not affect output, so you can use values containing spaces freely
```

A good way to verify is using `od -c` to show the actual chars.

```bash
me@host:~ 
$ echo -n bXlwYXNzd29yZA== | base64 -d | od -c
0000000   m   y   p   a   s   s   w   o   r   d
0000012
```

You see no "\n" is added. But if you use "echo" without "-n", `od` will show "\n":

```bash
me@host:~ 
$ echo mypassword | base64 -w 0
bXlwYXNzd29yZAo=me@host:~ 
$ echo bXlwYXNzd29yZAo= | base64 -d | od -c
0000000   m   y   p   a   s   s   w   o   r   d  \n
0000013
```

---

At last, create a function will help you in the future:

```bash
base64-encode() {
    if [ -z "$@" ]; then
        echo "Encode string with base64; echoing without line break, and base64 does not print line break neither, to not introducing extra chars while redirecting. Provide the string to encode. "
        return 1
    fi
    echo -n "$@" | base64 -w 0  # here I suppose string if containing space is already quoted
}
```

Comment: base64 doesn't seem to have a `-w` option on my system, what does it stand for (whitespace)?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and `base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.28`. It stands for `-w, --wrap=COLS       wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76). Use 0 to disable line wrapping`

Comment: ok. this isn't an option on the macOS version I have. thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, in that case do you have similar option/switch? Or you need to instead install GNU base64?

Comment: I think probably the latter, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: macOS by default is using `-w0` so I think you are fine without. Search here in stackoverflow and you will see it

Comment: Huh, I was searching here in stackoverflow, but anyway thanks

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463027/base64-doesnt-have-w-option-in-mac) from Google. Search here does not work well.

Comment: thanks, somehow google was unable to turn that up for me in a general search (which is how I ended up on this page)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to encode the string is using `cat` instead of `echo`, which makes your string be recorded in your bash history (`$HOME/.bash_history`).

With this command your string **will not** be recorded in your history, which may be useful if your string has credentials.

```bash
cat | tr -d "\n" | base64
```

Type your string, then press ENTER, then press CTRL+D.

Example:

```bash
user@computer$ cat | tr -d "\n" | base64
myuser:mypassword
bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Note that `tr -d "\n"` is removing the new line (LF) character.